# Android DCIM Folder Details

Tags: android, camera

I want to know that 100MEDIA folder in the DCIM is created byDefault or not. when i save the Image byDefault where it will stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the 100MEDIA folder can't be created by default, because on my nexus one I have only a 100ANDRO and a Camera folder inside the DCIM folder. The 100ANDRO is empty, the Camera is filled with images and videos I have taken.

As I just read a bit the documentation I guess there is no "default" folder to store a picture. I get an byte array which enables you to store the picture wherever you want.

Comment: I have a device of Android Version 1.6. There i see the 100MEDIA folder perhaps you are talking about the Android version 2.0 and above. but i want to know in Android 1.6 100MEDIA is default or not.